# Dynamically enable and disable sentry without stopping process?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sentry

I have many long-running processes that are using Sentry.io to report their errors. Starting and stopping these processes is expensive so we're trying to selectively disable Sentry without stopping the application.

It doesn't seem like there's a way to say `sentry_sdk.disable()` (or similar)

The best I can see is setting the `sample_rate=0.0` to effectively "disable" the integration by just not sending messages; we lose the RAM though.

Is there a better way, am I missing something?

Comment: You can call `init(None)` to disable the SDK, and then run your old `init()` code again to enable it. However, this will not affect already running threads other than the main one. I'd need more information about how your process works to be able to give you a more concrete answer.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer it must be threads hanging onto the configuration. We're using sentry in a thread-heavy + processs-heavy application so there's no way to know if all the threads cycled through the `init(None)`. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: What is the actual issue you're facing with the SDK's RAM consumption?

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer we're using Sentry on under-powered ARM devices. Enabling sentry adds ~1.8 MB to each process, or ~30 MB for the entire device. When we're already capped out this is a little more than 5% of our available RAM which is the difference between "works fine" and "doesn't work at all." However, the error reports are invaluable, so we're left with the trade off.

Comment: try decreasing `max_breadcrumbs` or setting `default_integrations=False` before you just disable the SDK. It could be that we just hold onto too many objects.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Sentry's BeforeEvent and return null:

```
   Sentry.init({
      beforeSend(event) {
        if (shouldSendEvent) return event;
        return null;
      }
    });
```